# Show only markers in given radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

i trying to make an algorithm that show only markers in a given radius this is my code:

```js
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        new google.maps.LatLng(user_logged_in[0][0],user_logged_in[0][1]),
        new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]));
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    var icon = {url:"http://".concat(markers[i][3]),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][4].toString().concat(' ').concat(markers[i][5].toString()),
        icon: icon, 
        url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'
    });
    if(<?=$this->translate($this->layout()->is_super_admin)?>==0){ 
        marker.setVisible(false);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#select-distance').change(function() {
                var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");
                var value =  parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
                if(d < value){                     
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    marker.setVisible(false); 
                }
                circle.setRadius(value);
                circle.bindTo('center', markerc, 'position');
                find_closest_marker(value);  
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But when I test it, it works only for the last user in the given radius. For example, if I have 3 users with distances 2km, 3km, 1km and I select a radius of 5km I get only the user with 3 km!!! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make new object of each marker and use that object.

See Below:

```
 //here use the var keyword and a new marker object
var marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: position,
         map: map,
         title: markers[i][4].toString().concat(' ').concat(markers[i][5].toString()),
         icon: icon, 
         url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'
     });

     if(<?=$this->translate($this->layout()->is_super_admin)?>==0){ 
         marker[i].setVisible(false);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#select-distance').change(function() {
             var e = document.getElementById("select-distance");
             var value =  parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
             if(d < value){                     
                marker[i].setVisible(true);
             }else{
                marker[i].setVisible(false); 
             }
             circle.setRadius(value);
             circle.bindTo('center', markerc, 'position');
             find_closest_marker(value);  
           });
        });
```

You are using the same object each time so it is replacing previous one. That's why it is drawing only last one marker.

Comment: i got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined !!!!

Comment: @samersboui and the line where you are getting this error.

Comment: var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
     });
     marker[i].addListener('mouseover', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent('<p><label>Name:</label> '+this.title+'</p>' +
                              '<center><a class="btn btn-primary" href="'+this.url+'">Call</a></center>'); 
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });   
     bounds.extend(position);
 }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

Comment: i edit it from marker.addListener to marker[i].addListener and i get a new error : Cannot read property '0' of undefined at the same ligne

Comment: @samersboui try after removing the `[i]` from marker and just add the var keyword only

Comment: i got only the last user but find_closest_marker(value);  function works correctly

Comment: @samersboui could you please make a fiddle for that so I can also check the  issue.